# Python Dash: Function should not run when n_clicks < 0 and defined in a call back

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am working on plotly dash app. I have an almost working example. The only thing that is not working is that I am not able to restrict the functions defined in the callbacks not to run when the page loads.

I have tried add checks for the n_clicks inside the callback however it doesnt seem to be working. It runs the function without the clicks as well

Below is the code for the dash

```
from datetime import date
import base64
import dash
import plotly
import dash

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from datetime import datetime as dt
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

import flask
import pandas as pd

server = flask.Flask('app')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash('app', server=server, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': '#EFEAEA', 'margin': '0px', 'padding': '0px'}, children=[
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode()),
                 style={'width': '200px', 'height': '100px', 'display': 'inline-block', 'float': 'left', 'padding-left': '5px', 'padding-top': '5px'})
        ]),
        html.Div([
            html.Div([
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='demographics',
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'All 18-49', 'value': '18_39'},
                            {'label': 'Female 25-54', 'value': '25_54 F'},
                            {'label': 'All 25-54', 'value': '25-54'},
                        ],
                        placeholder="Select Demographics",
                    )
                ],
                    style={'width': '30.5%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-right': '10px'}),
                html.Div([
                    dcc.DatePickerRange(
                        id='my-date-picker-range',
                        start_date_placeholder_text="Select a Start Date",
                        end_date_placeholder_text="Select an End Date",
                        min_date_allowed=dt(2018, 1, 1),
                        max_date_allowed=dt(2050, 12, 31),
                        initial_visible_month=dt(2019, 1, 2),
                        style={'width': '600', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-right': '10px'}
                    ),
                    html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-range')
                ],
                    style={'width': '30.3%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-right': '10px', 'position': 'relative'})

            ],
                style={
                'backgroundColor': '#EFEAEA',
                'padding': '5px 10px'}),
            html.Div([
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='Horsepower',
                        options=[
                            {'label': '200', 'value': 'two_hundred'},
                            {'label': '250', 'value': 'two_hundred_fifty'},
                            {'label': '300', 'value': 'three_hundred'},
                            {'label': '350', 'value': 'three_hundred_fifty'},
                            {'label': '400', 'value': 'four_hundred'}
                        ],
                        placeholder="Select TARP",
                    )
                ],
                    style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-right': '10px'}),
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='Kilometers',
                        options=[
                            {'label': '250,000', 'value': 250000, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '500,000', ''value': 500000, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '750,000', 'value': 750000, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': '1,000,000', 'value': 1000000, 'type': 'number'},
                        ],
                        placeholder="Select Impressions",
                    )
                ],
                    style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-right': '10px'}),
                html.Div([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='Speed',
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'Low', 'value': 50, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': 'Average', 'value': 100, 'type': 'number'},
                            {'label': 'High', 'value': 150, 'type': 'number'},
                        ],
                        placeholder="Select Frequency",
                    )
                ],
                    style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-right': '10px'}),
                html.Div([
                    html.Button('Submit', id='submit_button', type='submit', n_clicks=1,
                                style={'width': '100px', 'height': '34.5px', 'margin-bottom': '8px',
                                       'border-radius': '4px', 'display': 'inline-block', 'background-color': '#2D91C3', 'color': 'white'})
                ],
                    style={'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-bottom': '20px', 'verticalAlign': 'middle'}),
            ], style={
                'backgroundColor': '#EFEAEA',
                'padding': '5px'})
            ], style={'position': 'relative', 'left': '250px'})
        ]),

    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(id='example-graph', config={'modeBarButtonsToRemove': ['pan2d', 'lasso2d', 'sendDataToCloud',
                                                                             'select2d', 'autoScale2d', 'resetScale2d',
                                                                             'toggleSpikelines',
                                                                             'hoverClosestCartesian']})
        ],
            style={'width': '49.3%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'border': 'thin grey solid',  'margin-left': '5px',
                   'margin-right': '2.5px', 'margin-top': '5px', 'margin-bottom': '2.5px'}),
        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(id='example-graph1')
        ],
            style={'width': '49.3%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'border': 'thin grey solid', 'margin-left': '2.5px',
                   'margin-right': '5px', 'margin-top': '5px', 'margin-bottom': '2.5px', 'backgroundColor': '#EFEAEA'})
        ], style={'backgroundColor': '#EFEAEA'}),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='graph1')
    ],
        style={'width': '99.2%', 'height': '120%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'border': 'thin grey solid', 'margin-left': '2.5px',
               'margin-right': '5px', 'margin-top': '5px', 'margin-bottom': '2.5px', 'backgroundColor': '#EFEAEA'})
    ])


@app.callback(Output('example-graph1', 'figure'),
              [Input('submit_button', 'n_clicks')],
              [State('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
               State('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date')])

def update_graph(n_clicks, start_date,  end_date):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        df = df_new
        start_date_temp = dt.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        end_date_temp = dt.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        start_date_new = start_date_temp.replace(start_date_temp.year - 1)
        end_date_new = end_date_temp.replace(end_date_temp.year - 1)
        end_date_string = end_date_new.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        start_date_string = start_date_new.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        mask = (df['Date'] >= start_date_string) & (df['Date'] <= end_date_string)
        filtered_df = df.loc[mask]
        trace = Scatter(
            y=filtered_df['Weights'],
            x=filtered_df['Date'],
            line=plotly.graph_objs.scatter.Line(
                color='#42C4F7'
            ),
            hoverinfo='skip',
            error_y=plotly.graph_objs.scatter.ErrorY(
                type='data',
                array=filtered_df['Gender'],
                thickness=1.5,
                width=2,
                color='#B4E8FC'
            ),
            mode='lines'
        )
        layout1 = Layout(
            height=450,
            xaxis=dict(
                showgrid=False,
                showline=False,
                zeroline=False,
                fixedrange=True,
                title='Time Elapsed (sec)'
            ),
            yaxis=dict(
                showline=False,
                fixedrange=True,
                zeroline=False,

            ),
            margin=plotly.graph_objs.layout.Margin(
                t=45,
                l=50,
                r=50
            )
        )

        return Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout1)
    else:
        return {"I am the boss"}
```

The reason I presume the n_clicks checks is not working because I get the following error

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

I believe the error is because of the below code inside the function as the first time the page loads start_date would be none type.

```
start_date_temp = dt.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Can some one please help to resolve the issue. What I expect that when the page loads the call back function should not run.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: Just to be clear, you see this error when you load the page? I.e. before clicking the submit button for the first time?

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry, Yeah i see the error as soon as I load the page, before clicking on the submit button. When I give in the inputs in the date picker on the front end and click submit button. It works just fine and the graphs load perfectly. This is the only error I get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your problem:

`html.Button('Submit', id='submit_button', type='submit', n_clicks=1,`

You've preset `n_clicks` to have a value. Just remove that `n_clicks=1` part, and it will load the page as `None`. You will then need to check `n_clicks` like this (or similar):

`if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:`

It worked for me, and ran until it broke with my example `df`.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking one more thing. Is there any library you can think other than dcc.graph. I have been trying to use echarts, but somehow it has not been working.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with another that I could recommend.

Comment: There is one other thing, if you dont mind me asking. I have been trying to customise my datepickerrange. However I have been unable to do so. I have looked everywhere on internet however i have not found a single article which talks about how to customise the date picker range. Is there anyway I can customise my date picker range. I have updated my app layout if you want to have a look. I did not wanted to post another question just for this.

Comment: That may be worth another question, because you would have to explain in more detail how you want to customize it. I expect you've already checked them out, but here's [the docs](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/datepickerrange) just in case.

Comment: Sure, would do that. I have gone through this documentation but does not say anything about customising it in terms width and height

Comment: Hm, it has a `style` attribute. I haven't played around with this component, but some CSS might be able to get it looking the way you want.

Comment: I have tried using the style attribute but I have not been able to fix it. or may be I am not doing the right thing.

Comment: I have used CSS as well, but somehow it does not make any changes to the style of the datepicker range